# Clamping inrush current in a lighting circuit

Tags: relay, mains, inrush-current

I use a relay to switch on/off lighting circuits with lots of LEDs. The relay switches the mains supply so must run happily with 110/220/240 Vac. The relay I'm using is rated for an 800 A inrush current, which is the highest spec that I can find in its class and is sufficient to protect it from inrush damage with most LED lighting circuits, e.g. when the steady state current is less than say 10 A. So far, so good.

My problem: I would like to increase the maximum load, e.g. from 10 A to 15 A.

I think this means somehow clamping the inrush current, rather than simply using a bigger relay. I would prefer not to use a thermistor, because of the high temperatures these generate.

Is there a different (and cost-effective) solution?

Comment: Use a triac light dimmer circuit to ramp up the current.

Comment: a triac dimmer would only act on the control of the led supply, the actual capacitor which gives the inrush will be charged before the circuit detect it. Anyway the stated inrush is unreasonable

Comment: @lorenzo. Triacs and scrs are commonly used to limit the startup current in switched mode supplies and motors. You start with a low phase angle so that the available voltage is low which limits the peak charging current. As the phase angle increases, the available voltage also increases thus charging the capacitors gently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  a combo NTC and relay approach.  The NTC is in series for a short period of time, and then the relay is engaged to bypass the NTC.
[TDK has an appnote](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/en/373562/tech-library/articles/applications-cases/applications-cases/combined-current-control/2292312) on a simple RC timer based circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzoCqj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I would use two relays. The first relay switches the mains, with inrush limited by the thermistor. After a short delay, the second relay bypasses the thermistor, so it doesn't get hot (or at least it cools down again). Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you measured the actual inrush of you LED power supplies?
Good ones have soft start and don't inrush a lot. Also 800A inrush for 10A of steady state load is 80x, which is unreasonable. Where did you find that spec?

Standard *magnetic* breaker (curve C, IIRC) trip at 5x their current, for comparison so there something suspicious in your data

The obvious solution of course would be simply to… use more than one relay. Split the load between two contacts and put the coils in parallel. For optimum result if possible stagger the turn on to reduce the inrush on the network (you don't want to pop a fuse)

Comment: No, I haven't measured the inrush so this is empirical testing. I previously used lower spec relays but their contacts fused with LEDs. I changed to the highest spec I could find.

I've read that capacitive inrush (e.g. LEDs) can be 100x steady state current, so 10/800A is the right order of magnitude, no?

I've thought about multiple relays, but surely all the inrush would hit whichever relay closes first rather than both equally?

Comment: each relay would take the inrush of its led group. 100x is awful if they actually are so

Comment: Ah, I get it: you mean split the LEDs into, say, two groups and control each with a separate relay?